# where i put the third party jar files in sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2 in J2me?

Tags: java-me

I want to put the third party jar  file in my j2me application.but i dont know where i put the third party jar files in sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2.

Comment: I dont know why are u asking into sun java toolkit? how to developing ur j2me application? are u using any IDE?

Comment: You should better describe what kind of third party libs you want to use, and for what purpose. Further, what is your working/develeopment environment, Eclipse, NetBeans, or plain Ant files? Help us understand what you are doing!

Comment: thanks.... we are never used any ide for J2me application development.Just type the source code in text file and compile and run through the Sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2. Now i want to include third party jar file JEP. It contains set of classes,interfaces and methods for evaluating mathematical expression.suppose,my String like this:"2*532(25/3)" . this jar helps me to evaluate this String.How i do it... help me  get this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon creating a new project, the console messages tell where to put libraries(3rd party jar).  This is the *lib* directory of the project:

```
Creating project "Test"
Place Java source files in "/export/home/frayser/j2mewtk/2.5.2/apps/Test/src"
Place application resource files in "/export/home/frayser/j2mewtk/2.5.2/apps/Test/res"
Place application library files in "/export/home/frayser/j2mewtk/2.5.2/apps/Test/lib"
```

From FAQ: [I created a new project. Now what do I do?](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/FAQ.html)